# Deposits in the context of linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, finance, operations-research

Suppose that $x$ is amount invested in the low-risk term deposit and $y$ is amount invested in the balanced deposit, and $z$ is amount invested in the high-risk deposit.

To minimize risk, you decide not to invest any more than $\$2 000$ in the high-risk deposit and you decide to play safe and invest at least three times as much in the low-risk deposit than in the balanced deposit.

Do these two expressions equate to $z\leq 2000$ and $3y\leq x$?

Comment: Mathematically yes, but in the real world no.  In the real world, the diversification value between low and balanced risk deposits becomes close to worthless, if an inordinate amount of your funds are going into the high-risk deposit.  Normally, you would probably want to choose some value of $k > 1$ and also accept the third constraint that $kz \leq y.$